# Can trusted host settings use an IP address?

Tags: configuration

I'm working with a test site installed on a server on my network. Since it's only a sandbox, it has no domain name. Drupal being installed in a sub-directory (there are several sandboxes), I access it through an address like this: http://10.156.222.145/d8

However, when I put this in the trusted host patterns, like so:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
    '^10\.156\.222\.145\/d8$',
    '^localhost$'
  );
```

I get the error message: "The provided host name is not valid for this server."

Question: is it even possible to configure these settings with an IP address, and if so how?

Comment: Host names don't contain the path - have you tried `'^10\.156\.222\.145$'`?

Comment: That works! I thought I would have to put the exact path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes using an IP is fine, you just need to make sure you're using a valid host name (I.e. one without the path appended):

```
^10\.156\.222\.145$
```